# How to check if a differential operator is translation invariant practically?

Tags: differential-geometry, greens-function

Recently I was calculating some stuff in curved (ADs to be exact) spaces, when the following question came to my mind,
Suppose you have in general a differential operator $\hat{D}$ acting on the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ such that,
$$\hat{D}g_{\mu\nu} = T_{\mu\nu}$$
where $T_{\mu\nu}$ is a stress tensor (just an indexed space-time function for now).

**Question:**
What are the necessary conditions for the Green's function of $\hat{D}$ to be translation invariant, that is $G(x,x') = G(|x-x'|)$?

As far as my knowledge goes, translation invariance of the Green's function corresponds to an invariance/symmetry of the operator $\hat{D}$ itself. What practical checks do I perform on $\hat{D}$ to see if it is translation invariant ? I tried to solve it but made absolutely no progress, nor found any relevant literature. Can someone help by pointing out relevant literature and/or explaining a procedure to check the translation invariance?

Comment: If you have an expression for $\hat D$ then there should be no dependence on position, only on derivatives. For example, $x \partial_x$ is not translation invariant while $\partial_x^3 - \partial_y$ is.

Comment: I understand what you mean. However, say for the covariant derivative of a tensor of type (0,2), is the operator (the derivative) translation invariant ? @md2perpe